# PHP contact form: can I take the value of a span instead of an input?

Tags: php, html, contact-form

I'm setting up a contact form, but I have some saved information in some spans (It's an ecommerce shopping basket) and the built in checkout is awful so we're just slapping together an easy solution: turn it into an email form and email us the order instead of losing customers.

Anyway, can I use the info in the span, taking the `id` or `name` or do I have to turn it into an input? And if I do, how can I disable the input field?

Example of code I want to take into the email is in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LeYAj/), I want the spans with name="ACTUAL PRICE" etc emailed. Is this possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: are you really emailing yourself credit card information/payment information from customers?

Comment: No, we're not. We don't accept CC payment at the moment, we're a small company and just need the item info and their email address etc. Don't worry, we're using https. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a hidden input field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="foobar" />
```

It is not displayed, but can be used to submit information with the form.

Comment: I think I'll go down this route. Much easier to set up. Thanks :)

Comment: yup, the hidden field is the ideal solution. i use it all the time =)

Answer (score 3):

You'd be far better off using hidden form fields if possible. Else if the user has JS disabled you may run in to issues down the line. Rare but possible.